# Using POD for CSS documentation

Tags: css, perldoc

I'm working on the frontend of a project which has a Perl backend. The CSS files are getting pretty big and complicated, and are in need of some documentation and Tables of Contents.

I looked at various guides, slides and blog posts where everyone suggest their own style of plain text formatting. There seems to be no good standard, making the documentation difficult to port, print, and read.

Since our other documentation is in POD (Plain Old Documentation) / perldoc I figured I could try using POD for the CSS as well, but this feels very unconventional and frankly a bit *weird*. I tried a simple:

```
/*
=pod
...
=cut
*/
```

and it reads fine in perldoc.

Before launch, we strip all comments from our CSS files so size would not be an issue.

Are there any other practical objections to documenting CSS with POD? Have you used some other standard to document your CSS?

Comment: CSS that's documented *at all* is a rarity in my experience. How big is "pretty big" here?  I've got about 2500 lines of CSS in my site and that doesn't seem very big.

Comment: It's split over several files, but it's not unlikely that it will grow over 10k lines. And this is with heavy planning and optimization in mind. It's a very big site, with lots of required styling exceptions.

Comment: I don't think I've ever come across in all my years working with the web, seen any site, however big, having 10,000 lines of CSS code. What styling and why do you have to handle for exceptions? Is it for older browsers? Have you pushed the philosophy of giving older browsers a lesser experience? Have you architected this the best way possible? Have you considered using approaches such as OOCS (http://wiki.github.com/stubbornella/oocss/)? See the video and slideshare presentations on it. We reduced our CSS code base by 50-60% following some principles from here.

Comment: Not all CSS is included on all pages. We use the OOCCS model on new code we write, but it is still likely to grow. We use browser specific CSS for IE, but that's not much. Our site uses customizations for 3 different viewport sizes, which means the CSS grows further in complexity.

Answer (score 0):

I have found [CSSDOC](http://cssdoc.net/) which is based on JavaDoc / DocBlock. Apparently it's not only me searching for a standard way of documenting advanced CSS files. It looks pretty promising, but since we already use POD for other parts of our project, it makes the most sense to use it for CSS as well.

That means we can generate a complete documentation of our site to any format we wish.